# Kubernetes Jobs or Pods for completion Jobs with auto scaling

Tags: linux, azure, kubernetes, containers, keda

I have CPU Intensive Jobs/tasks,

Need to run them in kubernetes, below is the process of job/task

1. We get request in terms queue or API Call
2. POd should be created and process the task ( few Jobs may run in  minutes, few in hours)
3. delete pod once task completed

This should happen in scale, if more jobs in queue, create more jobs (Max 10, 20, 30 2e should define it)

I am used KEDA, POD will be created and after Job completion it is going crashloopbback, It is default behaviour in POD life cycle, because it try to recreate pod since restart policy is set to Always. We have other options like OnFailure, Never, But I read it Kubernetes Jobs are more suitable

Which is the better option Kubernetes Pods or Jobs for above task, we should consider  scaling POds and also required scale kubernetes nodes (Cloud vendors supports it) based on usage and numbers of tasks in queue.

Answer (score 0):

KEDA [ScaledJobs](https://keda.sh/docs/2.3/concepts/scaling-jobs/) are best for such scenarios and can be triggered through Queue, Storage, etc. (the currently available scalers can be found [here](https://keda.sh/docs/2.3/scalers/))